# SharpDX: Method not found 'get_BufferPointer()'

Tags: c#, c++, graphics, directx-11, sharpdx

I've build a simple SharpDX project from the tutorial on indiedev ([#1](http://www.indiedev.de/wiki/SharpDX_Einstieg), [#2](http://www.indiedev.de/wiki/SharpDX:_Eine_einfache_Game-Klasse), [#3](http://www.indiedev.de/wiki/SharpDX:_Das_erste_Dreieck)).

Now I run into a error **Method not found 'IntPtr SharpDX.D3DCompiler.ShaderBytecode.get_BufferPointer()'** when i start the application.

I've a reference to the follwoing SharpDX dll's:

- SharpDX.D3DCompiler
- SharpDX.Direct3D11
- SharpDX.DXGI
- SharpDX

this code is the main loop:

```
public void Run()
{
   //...
   Initialize();
   LoadContent();

   RenderLoop.Run(renderWindow, () =>
   {
      //....
   }
   //...
}

public override void LoadContent()
{
   ShaderBytecode vertexShaderByteCode = ShaderBytecode.CompileFromFile("shaders.hlsl", "VShader", "vs_4_0");
   ShaderBytecode pixelShaderByteCode = ShaderBytecode.CompileFromFile("shaders.hlsl", "PShader", "ps_4_0");

    vertexShader = new VertexShader(Device, vertexShaderByteCode); //--> error
    pixelShader = new PixelShader(Device, pixelShaderByteCode);
    //...
 }
```

the content from the shaders.hlsl:

```
struct VOut
{
  float4 position : SV_POSITION;
  float4 color    : COLOR;
};

VOut VShader(float4 position : POSITION, float4 color : COLOR)
{
  VOut output;

  output.position = position;
  output.color = color;

  return output;
}

float4 PShader(float4 position : SV_POSITION, float4 color : COLOR) : SV_TARGET
{
  return color;
}
```

What do I have to add to the shaders.hlsl file?

Comment: That's not a shader file problem (although, your pixel shader should take a single parameter of type `VOut`). The runtime can't find a method that something is trying to call. Do you have SharpDX.D3DCompiler.dll in your output directory?

Comment: Thanks for your replay. But I've SharpDX.D3DCompiler, SharpDX.Direct3D11, SharpDX.DXGI and SharpDX in the output directory and also as reference in my project. I updated my question to clarrify it.

Comment: OK, cool. What version are they? Did you get them via NuGet? You might not have the latest versions.

Comment: Thanks I had a old version and now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is the cause of an old assembly Version. As [Chris Mantle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/718972/chris-mantle) mentioned it helps to update to the newest version via NuGet. You can get it from [here](http://www.nuget.org/packages?q=sharpdx).

It was no problem with the shaders.hlsl file. all works now fine.